# Как писать приложения под android на C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, android, .net

Я asp.net разработчик, и хочу изучить android разработку. Не собираюсь переходить на android разработку, поэтому не хочу вложить много времени в изучение, но базовые вещи для написания приложений очень хотелось бы знать. Что нужно для android разработки: платформа, книги, полезные материалы и тд?

Comment: И ещё я правильно понимаю, что востребованность C# android developers намного меньше чем java android developers?

Comment: Решил писать под андроид на джаве. Вопрос закрыт, всем спасибо! Кто хочет помочь пишем сюда: http://hashcode.ru/questions/205098/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-android-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще если уж так захотелось писать под Android именно на Шарпе, то могу сказать, что небезызвестная компания Xamarin  (та, что реализует .NET под прочие, отличные от Windows, платформы) около года тому назад объявила о выпуске проекта Mono for Android, о чем неоднократно писалось наХабре ([вот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/169467/), [вот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/119001/) и [вот](http://habrahabr.ru/post/170629/)). Официальный сайт сего чудо-проекта находится [тут](http://xamarin.com/monoforandroid) (с кучей документации, между прочим. Впрочем, качество этой кучи оценивать не берусь). Господа из Xamarin, между прочим, утверждают, что их реализация работает куда как быстрее, чем Dalvik. Но, надо сказать ,что бесплатно вы сможете отлаживать свое творчество только под эмулятором. Отладка на реальном устройстве возможна лишь при покупке лицензии.
Ну и еще есть [книга](http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Android-Programming-Mono-NET/dp/1118026438) по разработке под Android с помощью Mono (кстати говоря, полагаю, что подобной литературы на два порядка меньше, чем для разработчиков на Java)

Comment: Конечно хорошо бы разрабатывать на джаве, но для изучения нового языка нужно время, даже несмотря на то, что синтаксис там очень похожий.

Comment: ну так если хотите заняться этим исключительно в качестве хобби 9даже если предполагаете ,что оно может перерасти в нечто большее со временем), то попробуйте Mono. Хоть условия бесплатного пользования там довольно сильно ограничивают вашу свободу действий, все же в целях "потренироваться на кошках" вполне сгодится и это

Answer (score 0):

Кроме упомянутого моно есть [dot42](http://www.dot42.com/). Компилятор шарпа в дальвик (Проект еще молодой, но для простых приложений сгодиться).

Answer (score -1):

- платформа - любая, но лучше Linux
- книги - любые, главное не русскоязычные ("виды" и "деятельности" меня коробят)
- полезные материалы - d.android.com
- и самое главное - нужно немного призабыть шарп и выучить Java.