# Как писать приложения под android на Java?

Tags: c#, eclipse, android, java, visual-studio

Здравствуйте все. Совсем недавно я задавал вопрос - ["Как писать приложения под android на C#?"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/205041/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4-android-%d0%bd%d0%b0-c)

Теперь я решил, что возможно стоит изучить разработку под андроид на джаве, хотя бы потому что бесплатный monodroid вообще ничего не может. Следовательно возникают новые вопросы. Нужно ли учить джаву или зная C# джава будет интуитивно понятной? И можно ли интегрировать java android разработку в visual studio или нужно eclipse использовать? И опять же, что для этого нужно установить, прочитать изучить, и тд?

Comment: Мой выбор это IntelliJ IDEA (достаточно CE). Про visual studio сомневаюсь.

Comment: ну с Android SDK ставится eclipse сразу же готовый к использованию, но соглашусь что в IntelliJ IDEA было бы намного приятнее работать. А его как то настраивать надо чтобы он увидел SDK и эмулятор, или он при установке все увидит ?

Comment: Ну указать месторасположение android-sdk один раз можно и все будет нормально. Когда то давно пробовал перейти на идею с эклипса, не понравилось. После того как купил идею (и в принципе основные, не андроид проекты, делаю там), решил снова попробовать под андроид пописать и был приятно удивлен изменениям.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

К сожалению или к счастью (каждый решает за себя сам нужную сторону) разработка для Android предполагает принятие на себя некоторых ограничительных мер, а именно:

1. Забываем про любимый язык (C#, Python, Pascal) и переходим на Java или С/С++
2. Забываем про любимую среду разработки (Visual C++, Netbeans и проч.) и переходим на Eclipse или Intellij IDEA

Возможен путь героя, когда берем C# с Mono (или Python и проч.) и начинаем разработку становясь подопытным кроликом разработчиков соответствующих тулзов. Правда, при этом надо четко осознавать, что разработки нормальной не будет - будет только головная боль.

Разработка под Android это достаточно mature деятельность, которая не подразумевает отклонений [от шаблонов](http://developer.android.com/tools/index.html), что впрочем не отменяет путь героя.

**Update**

1. Изучать Java нужно - Java проще C#, и именно поэтому нужно ее изучать - чтобы понять ее простоту и мощь. У шарпистов обычно мозги вывернуты не в ту сторону из-за неоправданной сложности C#
2. Надо установить JDK v.6 (не надо 7-ю!), взять [EAP версию Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html) и написать что-нить на vanilla Java

Comment: >> Возможен путь героя, когда берем C# с Mono (или Python и проч.) 

Настоящий герой сам напишет свой набор инструментов под свой любый язык:)

Comment: Вы не ответили на самые важные вопросы: нужно ли учить джаву или она интуитивно понятна для C# разработчика, что нужно изучить прочитать установить и тд?

Comment: @jojo97 см. апдейт ответа

Comment: Почему 7 не надо? И что такое vanilla java?

Comment: учитывая, что Оракл как может прижимает 6 джаву, рекомендовать ее считаю плохо. 7 вполне себе работает.

Comment: JDK 7 не работает для Android'а... Vanilla Java это Java в редакции Sun/Oracle. Android'овская Java немного другая, в частности у нее другой формат байткодов и не все либы поддерживаются.

Comment: jdk 7 не работает для андроида? ой, а как же это я тогда у себя на двух компьютерах без установленной java 6 живу... И пол офиса ещё живет и не переживает.

>  Vanilla Java это Java в редакции Sun/Oracle.

а OpenJDK это ванила или нет?

> Android'овская Java

мда... не путаем виртуальную машину и язык?

Comment: "У шарпистов обычно мозги вывернуты не в ту сторону" - эт точно. Нет чтобы глянуть на какую-нибудь программку и самому решить, понятна ли она интуитивно, он нас спрашивает.

Comment: 1) Это всего лишь означает, что разработка кое у кого плохая раз JDK 7 работает :) Смотрим [системные требования](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) к Android и врубаемся почему ребята из Гугля такие тормозные :)2) OpenJDK эт не ванилла... :)3) А мы не путаем троллинг с дискуссией?