# Objective-C или C# для In-House разработки

Tags: c#, objective-c, ios, iphone

И так, нашей команде дали задание - научиться мобильной разработке. Из знаний у нас Java, у некоторых Scala. Целевая платформа – iOs, позже Android. На прицеле 2 фрэймворка и 2 языка - C# и Objective-C. Так как зная Java мы знаем на 60% C# я сам склоняюсь к Mono, плюс скорость разработки на Mono. Однако на Objective-C более быстрые программы, так? Объясните пожалуйста за каждый фрэймворк.

Comment: Смотря что нужно разрабатывать...
Человекоориентированные через (Виртуальные машины):
-------
А в целом Java - ваще не вариант,
Flash  AIR - как вариант, но не вариант,
PhoneGap Javascript - вариант, но не вариант,
С#  через моно - не вариант, но как вариант,
-------
Вроди бы человекоориентированный, но на выходе все же чистый С либо С++:
Objective-c (Тоже что и C) или Objective-cpp (Тоже что и С++)- по всем параметрам вариант. 

и таким образом вы юзая objective-с плюс:
Android NDK = нативная 
IOS = по умолчанию нативная
BlackBerry SDK = нативная
Можно написать JVM еще одну на Objective-c..

Comment: Я считаю, и это имхо, что лучше С ничего нет, а лучшее в С это Objective-c или Smalltalk‎. Хотя могу ошибаться.

Answer (score 2):

Objective-C == стандартный сдк == доступ ко всем возможностям платформы + готовые сторонние сдк для iOs тоже на нем будут в первую очередь (на вскидку из частоиспользуемых на ум сразу приходит facebook и dropbox), ну и как вы верно заметили программы теоретически быстрее т.к. это компилируемый язык. Кстати с C++ он тоже дружит из коробки если вдруг надо, а с С так и вовсе полностью совместим

Про моно ничего сказать не могу, не использовал

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C.
Если смотреть на него без предубеждений предыдущих изученный Вами языков - это самый простой ООП-язык. Тем более что не придется сталкиваться с уродством кроссплатформенной разработки как уже указали в ответах этого треда наши коллеги. Только Ваше руководство должно быть готово вложиться в железо, на виртуальных машинах или хакинтошах Ваше горе может сравняться с горем кроссплатформенной разработки.

Comment: Мы и так все на маках сидим :). Поэтому и возник вопрос. И так, благодаря вам решил - идем на Objective C. Спасибо :)

Comment: Так если железо есть то это вообще путь наименьшего сопротивления. Веселого кодинга Вам!

Answer (score 0):

Забудьте про Mono - уже известно, что платформа сырая и под ней ничего толком не сделать. Буквально месяц назад один падаван уже пытался что-то сварганить на ней, через недедю выкинул с криками %***%!!!!

**Update**
[см. дискуссию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/205098/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-android-%D0%BD%D0%B0-java)